# How can I score a code golf challenge, with added complexity?

Tags: discussion

I've had a couple challenges in mind that are somewhat along the lines of:

> Do *x* in as many ways as possible, with as little code as possible.

However, I'm having a hard time settling on how to score this. I'd like a way that gives fair weight to the "many ways" factor while still very much encouraging a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) mentality.

I've already seen tags or suggestions for "code chess", "code bowling", "atomic code golf", etc - most of which seem to not have gone over well. Is this a similarly bad idea? Or is there already another name for it, and a standard means of scoring?

Comment: Can you objectively define whether two programs are solving the task in the same way?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes. Wouldn't be a really fair challenge if you couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
  number of ways
-----------------   ?
 character count
```

Of course, it will need to be complicated enough that there are no 1-3 character solutions.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, the higher score should win? My first thought was actually the inverse - `characters/ways` - and low score wins. Any thoughts on problems I might encounter, or should avoid, other than the 1-3 character thing?

Comment: yeah, that's a high score wins metric. The inverse is just as good

Comment: Define "number of ways". If it's ambiguous, people will stretch it. Also, beware of cases where linear growth of code length causes superlinear growth of the number of ways.